# How to use gatsby-source-strapi-localized

Tags: internationalization, gatsby, strapi

I'm trying to get a simple website to support both English and Spanish and after some digging and research on which plugin would suit my needs better, I've found this one: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-strapi-localized/

So I tried and configure it in my project the same way its configured in the example:

[image: PLugin Configuration]

And I've created a Content-Type called article on Strapi that has a title__en and title__es but when I run gatsby develop and open the GraphQL console I can't find the locales query, I just see this:

[image: GraphQL]

Any idea on how to fix this? Has anyone used the gatsby-source-strapi-localized before?

Answer (score 0):

In the `gatsby.congig.js` file, use the `gatsby-source-strapi-localized` resolve instead of `gatsby-source-strapi`.